# Flujo de un bucle While dentro de una función

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

alguien que me pueda explicar el flujo de esta función y de por que el bucle solo imprime un resultado, en pantalla me imprime el numero 11 y no entiendo cómo llega a dar esto.

```
def sumDigit(num):
    sum = 0
    while(num):
        sum += num % 10
        num = int(num / 10)
    return sum
print(sumDigit(821))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ver todo el flujo puedes imprimir los datos en cada paso como por ejemplo:

```
def sumDigit(num):
    sum = 0
    print("antes del while sum = %d" % sum)
    while(num):
        print("recibido num = %d" % num)
        sum += num % 10
        print("sum = %d" % sum)
        num = int(num / 10)
        print("num = %d" % num)
    return sum
print("resultado = %d" % sumDigit(821))
print()
```

El resultado es el siquiente:

```
antes del while sum = 0
recibido num = 821
sum = 1
num = 82
recibido num = 82
sum = 3
num = 8
recibido num = 8
sum = 11
num = 0
resultado = 11
```

Comment: Gracias! Me ha quedado claro. :)

Comment: Si te ha quedado claro no dudes en aceptar la respuesta como valida

Answer (score 2):

Ese print está fuera del while, por eso imprime solamente una vez.
Te sugiero que hagas la función con el print dentro y utilices variables, no números. Desde el main, llama a la función y ponle el número que quieras.

Sería algo así:

```
def sumDigit(num):
sum = 0
while(num):
    sum += num % 10
    num = int(num / 10)
    print(sumDigit(num))
return sum

void main()
sumDigit(821)
```

A lo mejor no hace lo que buscas, no entiendo demasiado bien qué pretendes conseguir.
Si no hace lo que dices, explícame qué quieres conseguir con tu programa.